# What is hybrid mode - corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics, hybrid

I don't understand what is the difference between `physics.setDrawMode("hybrid")` and `physics.setDrawMode("normal")`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Corona documentation the normal mode is --for the default Corona renderer, with no collision outlines, while the hybrid one is --overlays collision outlines on normal display objects. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/setDrawMode.html)

Comment: "outlines" you mean out of the screen?

Comment: @idanahal I guess so.

Answer (score 0):

To help debugging physics engine behaviour, Corona allows to set rendering mode to one of three:

- **normal** - doesn't show collision outlines

[image: normal mode]

- **hybrid** - shows collision outlines on display objects, [following  colors](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/setDrawMode.html) are used to distinguish between different bodies

  - orange — dynamic physics bodies
  - dark blue — kinematic physics bodies
  - green — static, non-moveable physics bodies
  - gray — a body that is "sleeping" due to lack of activity
  - light blue — physical joints (see the Physics Joints guide)

In the example below, the **floor's** outline is green, because it is a static, it doesn't move, as defined by the following code:

```
physics.addBody( floor, "static", { density=1.0, friction=0.3, bounce=0.2 } )
```

The **ball's** outline on the other hand, is orange when it's moving, and gray, when it's resting ("sleeping") on the floor.

[image]
[image: hybrid mode]

- **debug** - only collision engine outlines are shown;

[image: debug]

"hybrid"/"debug" modes will be useful when debugging collisions (as bounding boxes of objects are shown), object movement, physical properties etc.

So in short, the difference between "normal" and "hybrid" modes is that in "hybrid" mode, you can see the physics properties of the bodies.

Documentation [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/physicsSetup/index.html) and [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/setDrawMode.html).